# Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/mopub/mobileads/AdFetcher$FetchStatus;

Tags: android, dalvik, dex

Ever since the update that I've downloaded in the ADT, I can't test my apps.
My console keeps giving me this error:

```
Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/mopub/mobileads/AdFetcher$FetchStatus;
```

It implies that my mopub library isn't synching well with my main project.

I've moved my libraries to all my main project and to the other library, cleaned all projects and deleted/edited my build pathways in most possible ways, so is there anyone that has a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Somehow you're ending up with two copies of the library to be compiled. This usually happens when both your app and an included library depend on a third-party library.

For example:

```
Support lib -> App <- Library <- Support lib
```

Where `A <- B` means that A depends on B.

Remove the direct dependency in the app project and you will inherit the one from the library. In the example above that would be the dependency on the left.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The problem was that the project referenced android-support v4 in its own project and that of its library, so I took that one out and it works like a charm now!